# Detecting & Testing if the data is regularly spaced in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have the following time series. This is a subset, the real time series has 420,000 rows.

Problem: Detecting & Testing if the data is regularly spaced.

```
        USAF  WBAN        YR--MODAHRMN DIR
 1950 723890 93193 1972-08-31 15:00:00 280
 1951 723890 93193 1972-08-31 18:00:00 090
 1952 723890 93193 1972-08-31 21:00:00 150
 1953 723890 93193 1972-09-01 00:00:00 240 
 1954 723890 93193 1972-09-01 01:00:00 300
 1955 723890 93193 1972-09-01 02:00:00 290
```

The column that we need to check is "YR--MODAHRMN" which is:

```
 class(sdf$"YR--MODAHRMN")
 [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

Before observation 1952, the time series is taken every 3 hours, after 1953, every 1 hour.

Expected Result: I want R to tell me: "Yes, the data is hourly data" OR "No, the data is not hourly. There is a break in 1953" or something like this. I just want to make sure that the rest of my data is hourly data and not a mixture

Is there any way of testing in R if the time series is equally spaced. I need to have only hourly observations, but of course, I can't check the 420,000 observations one by one? Thanks

Comment: You can check `?diff` Try `df1[c(diff(df1$SPD)==1, TRUE),]` or some variation of time as it is not clear which rows you need to subset from the example

Comment: I don't need to subset. I need R to tell me "Yes, the rest is hourly data" or "No, not everything is hourly data" and maybe tell me where the break occurs

Comment: Please do update with the expected result so that it will be more clear

Comment: Updated the question to reflect what you said. There must be a time series package to figure this out, but i cant find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will only be a single difference if the series is regular spaced so try this:

```
# test data
ch <- c("1972-08-31 15:00:00", "1972-08-31 18:00:00", "1972-08-31 21:00:00", 
"1972-09-01 00:00:00", "1972-09-01 01:00:00", "1972-09-01 02:00:00")
p <- as.POSIXct(ch)

length(unique(diff(p)))
## [1] 2
```

If the length is 1 it is regularly spaced and if > 1 then not.  In this case the differences are all 1 or 3 hours; therefore, the number of unique differences is `2` and so it is not regularly spaced.  (We can examine `unique(diff(p))` to see what the differences are.)

(Note that the zoo package has a function called `is.regular`; however, its purpose is slightly different. It regards a series as regular if it is regularly spaced except possibly for some missing values.  In the example data here `is.regular` would regard the series as regular because if one filled the points that are 3 apart by two values that are 1 apart then it would be regularly spaced.)